# Fallback value for contextual filter, in case the "provided default value" does not exist

Tags: 7, views

I want to display a block on each page (nodes as well as pages created by Views) that displays links to nodes that are tagged with a certain taxonomy term.

How to decide which tag should be used:

- **{1}** If the page is a node that references a taxonomy term:
  use the referenced term
- **{2}** If the page is a node that doesn’t reference a taxonomy term (= empty value):
  use the term with ID 1
- **{3}** If the page is not a node (= created by Views):
  use the term with ID 1

I managed to get the links shown in case **{1}**, by using the relationship "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" and the contextual filter "Taxonomy term: Term ID" which uses the relationship.

I selected "Provide a default value" (Type: "Taxonomy term ID from URL" + "Load default filter from node page, that’s good for related taxonomy blocks"). So I can’t specify the default value here for case **{2}** and **{3}**.

Then I thought I could use the validation options somehow, but "Action to take if filter value does not validate" does not allow me to set a specific value in case the original default value does not exist.

How could I solve this?

**tl;dr:** I need something like: Take term ID from URL (via node ID), and if this gives no term ID, use term ID 1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your contextual filter to return 1 when the value is not available like so:

[image: Drupal Answer]

Comment: But I already used this field for case {1}, to provide the term ID as default value.

Comment: I think your only solution is to use Php code on the contextual filters then. Check if it's a node, then use node_load(), check taxonomy term and return it, if it's not a node return 1